# Navigate to login when JWT token expires

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, jwt

Hi I'm quite new to this. I'm trying to navigate the user to the login page when the JWT token expires but I'm struggling with it. I was thinking maybe I need to set a timeout when the login action is dispatched? The token expires in 8 hours ( what the backend dev said ). I used jwt-decode to decode the token. I would appreciate any tip

ProtectedRoutes.js

```js
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

export default function ProtectedRoutes() {

var token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
 
// console.log(decoded);

// console.log(decoded.exp)

  const isAuthActive = () => {
    const expiryTime = new Date(decoded.exp * 1000).toLocaleString(
      'en-sg'
    );
    const currentTime = new Date().toLocaleString('en-sg');
    if (expiryTime < currentTime) {

      sessionStorage.remove("token");
      return <div>{isAuthActive ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" />}</div>;
    }
    return true;
  }
  
let userid = sessionStorage.getItem("token") == null ? false : true;
 return <div>{userid ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" />}</div>;
```

authService.js

```js
const login = async (formData) => {
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_STAGING_URL}/api/v1/auth/signin`,
    formData
  );

  if (response.data) {
    const { token } = response.data;
    sessionStorage.setItem("token", token);
  }
  return response.data;
};

const logout = async () => {
  const response = await axios.post(
    `${import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_STAGING_URL}/api/v1/auth/logout`
  );

  if (response.data) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem("token");
  }
  return response.data;
};
```

authSlice.js

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authService from "./authService";

const initialState = {
  user: localStorage.getItem('user') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) : null,
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  }
  
 // User Login
export const login = createAsyncThunk("auth/signin", async (formData, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    return await authService.login(formData);
  } catch (error) {
    const message =
      (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.message) ||
      error.message ||
      error.toString();
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(message);
  }
});

export const logout = createAsyncThunk("auth/logout", async () => {
  await authService.logout();
});

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => {
      (state.isLoading = false),
        (state.isSuccess = false),
        (state.isError = false),
    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isError = true;
        state.user = null;
      })
      .addCase(logout.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(logout.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.user = null;
      });
  },
});

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Do you *need* to log the user out and redirect to authenticate as soon as the token expires, or just when they navigate to a protected route *after* it expires? If the former then yes, setting a timeout would likely be appropriate. If the latter then what you have seems fine. Can you clarify what the exact behavior should be that you want?

Comment: I would like the user to be redirected as soon as the token expires.

Comment: Note that after asking a question and getting clarficiation feedback which points out what seems to be a logical error, it is not considered politely grateful to delete the question. People spent time on your question and helped you. In return you should not silently deny them recognition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like the user to be deauthenticated and redirected to log in again as soon as the token expires then I would suggest using a mounting `useEffect` hook callback to check the current token value's expiration and conditionally set a timeout when the token will expire during a "session" or if as soon as the app starts/mounts it is already expired to log out and redirect the user.

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const token = useSelector(state => state.auth.user.token);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timerRef = null;

    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

    const expiryTime = (new Date(decoded.exp * 1000)).getTime();
    const currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();

    cont timeout = expiryTime - currentTime;
    const onExpire = () => {
      dispatch(logout());
      navigate("/auth/login");
    };

    if (timeout > 0) {
      // token not expired, set future timeout to log out and redirect
      timerRef = setTimeout(onExpire, timeout);
    } else {
      // token expired, log out and redirect
      onExpire();
    }

    // Clear any running timers on component unmount or token state change
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerRef);
    };
  }, [dispatch, navigate, token]);

  ...
};
```